# Handler to Fetch Event Data for Firebase/Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

I want to make a handler that can fetch data from the google analytics events from my website. The ultimate goal is to use this handler to display data on an admin page. How would I go about creating this handler in javascript? I am using firebase and google analytics on my website.

The other resources I found online I dont think are up to date so I really have no clue where to start.

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.